# How to bind objects to specific parameters (not types) in Laravel's service container

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-10, laravel-service-container

Context: From a Laravel service container, we can easily bind abstracts to concrete implementations, and variables to scalar types, using the following, respectively:

```
// Abstracts to concrete implementations
$this->app->when(Foo::class)->needs(Bar::class)->give(new FooBar);

// Variables to scalars
$this->app->when(Foo::class)->needs('$bar')->give('fooBar');
```

Problem: I want to bind concrete classes to specific constructor variables (so a combination of the two), but it won't let me:

```
$this->app->when(Foo::class)->needs('$bar')->give(new FooBar);
```

That just returns:

```
Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException
Target [FooBar] is not instantiable while building [Foo].
```

At least, when the constructor variable is typed to FooBar, not when it's `mixed`. But setting it to `mixed` is not acceptable to me.

```
// Doesn't work:
class Foo
{
    public function __construct(
        protected FooBar $foo,
    )
    {
    }
}

// Works:
class Foo
{
    public function __construct(
        protected mixed $foo,
    )
    {
    }
}
```

To be clear, the `new FooBar` I want to inject is dynamically resolved, so I can't just `new Foo(new FooBar)`, and I need this to work for multiple constructor arguments of the same type (which are each bound to different implementations), along with other dependencies:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct(
        protected FooBar $primaryFoo, // e.g. new Foobar('green')
        protected FooBar $secondaryFoo, // e.g. new FooBar('blue')
        // ... Other dependencies
    )
    {
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what syntax to use and I can't find anything that points to this in the docs or in the foundation code. It doesn't seem like I can achieve this with `bind()` as that is meant for use with abstracts. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not to bind like $this->app->bind(Foo::class, fn() => new Foo(new Bar, new Bar))

Comment: @Maksim Because there are other dependencies to resolve through the container. I can't really combine that in bind(), right? Returning `$this->app->make()` from the closure results in an infinite loop?